# Using a thread to control an object that access an external api

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, c++-cli

I trying to write a program that talks to an external license system. This program, which is a license manager, handles several product licenses.

For each product installed that the license manager detects, it initializes the license system by doing api calls using the license SDK.

Using a regular class it's easy, because I can just wrap the api and call a member functions to initialize and done. I can later retrieve more information about the license if i need to, since I'm using the class that already initialized the license via api call. And when i close my program i do a call stop license and done.

Now what I would like to do is, for each product and its license, I want to create a thread to manage this wrapper object to perform api calls and talk to the license system.

Below is an example of what I'd like to do:

```html
Class LicenseWraper
{
  LicenseWrapper()
  {
    // this is a C api call from the license SDK
    StartLicense();
  }
  
  ~licenseWrapper
  {
    // this is a C api call from the license SDK
    EndLicense();
  }
  
  string GetLicenseInfo()
  {
    // this is a C api call from the license SDK
    return GetLicenseInfoApi();
  }
}

void main()
{
  LicenseWraper oLicense = new LicenseWrapper();
  string sMyInfo = oLicense.GetLicenseInfo();
}
```

Based on my limited knowledge of multithreading, I can only pass a function to the thread to do the work and done. If I create the `licenseWrapper` object in the thread via a delegate or a dedicate function then it will sure enough create the object and initialize the license system OK.

However, now that the license system is initialized, I would like to retrieve the license info via `oLicense.GetLicenseInfo()`. My understanding is that I cannot do that call from the thread that created the object, so the `oLicense.GetLicenseInfo()` call will not work since it is now being called from the outside thread.

So my question is this: How can I use a thread to manage an object and keep that object alive so that I can do api calls from that thread. Is it even possible to do this?

Any insight or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just make it a global variable, one license provider is enough for everybody.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the comment but i quite did not understand what you mean by having a global license. can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Each thread you create has its own stack (1 MB by default) and a snapshot of CPU registers, called together a context. (There are more things associated with a thread, like TLS and apartment state, but lets keep it simple).
I assume you are building for Windows, but the following is true for any thread abstraction library, you go after.
Threads in Win32 are created with a call to CreateThreadEx (see MSDN), one of the parameters is the address to the entry point, the so called ThreadProc, which takes LPVOID as parameter and there's another parameter of type LPVOID called lParameter. 
Now, as I said above, each thread gets its own stack. Thus, if you want to share data between them, you need to store it on the heap.
Create a pointer to pointer (Licence** pLicence) and pass it as lParameter. Then in the ThreadProc cast LPVOID back to the pointer and initialize it like that: *pLicence = oLicence.GetLicenceInfo(); 
Now, you have to notify the main thread that the background thread has done its job. There are many ways to do that, like PostMessage()